# Podman doesn´t respond on connection from different host

Tags: elasticsearch, networking, logstash, podman, podman-compose

I was using docker-compose and network_mode: host for apps in docker.
I was using ELK stack and I have some more VM machines, where I have java apps.
I need to send logs via Logback to Logstash but I need to switch from docker to podman.
I made question to ELK but I must say, this isnot related to ELK problem.
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/what-network-mode-use-in-podman-compose/321914

So.
[connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLTf4.png)

How should I set up bridge on my ELK VM?
Right now I can connect all APPS on ELK VM together but I cant connect from APP VMs (1,2,3) to Logstash, which is ingest on port 6379. Because it seems like podman not respons.
(topic on forum - https://discuss.elastic.co/t/what-network-mode-use-in-podman-compose/321914)

I tried some other podman networking but I cant see any host option, I tried macvlan but thats not what I wanted, I want to have functional bridge connection between APP VMs and podman pods on ELK VM without dropping connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I removed docker but he left his chain in iptables, when I rebooted VM then everything was fine.
So solved by reboot :)